# permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks" with gson deserialization

Tags: java, applet, deserialization, gson, appletviewer

I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")

at

andpyt692.CalendarApplet$ItemChangeListener.itemStateChanged(CalendarApplet.java:96)
```

which is

```
Days = jin.fromJson(json, listType);
```

On appletviewer everything's OK - problem shows when I'm trying to open applet in browser. Problem just like [Java: Using Gson in an Applet causes SecurityException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850859/java-using-gson-in-an-applet-causes-securityexception) but nothing I've seen there really helps me. I don't feel like giving up gson, is there any way I can solve it?